# Uncaught type error cannot read property 'event' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a simple app that writes the values entered in a form on the console:

HTML:

```
<input type="email" name="email-address" value="" id="email-address" />

<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Login" onclick="login_existing_submit()" id="register-submit" />
```

Javascript:

```
function login_existing_submit() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("email-address").value);            
}
```

Comment: Where is your email-address...?

Comment: It didnt show up even though I put it but just refreshed and its there.

Comment: It sounds as though the function may not be available in the JS scope.  How is the page constructed to load the JS in relation to the rest of the page.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You can't use hyphen in IDs.

```
<input type="email" name="email-address" value="" id="emailaddress" />

function login_existing_submit() 
{
    console.log(document.getElementById("emailaddress").value);            
}
```

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/drAUB/)

Comment: You can't use hyphens in JavaScript _identifiers_ due to `-` also being an operation.  DOM ids treated as strings will work (though may be better avoided).

Comment: I think you can use hyphens in IDs

Comment: When I removed the hyphen from the submit button's id it worked even thought the other elements still have hyphens. So its generally a good idea to eliminate hyphens from id's.Thanks a lot!!!.

Comment: Its wrong information going to represent over here. There is no restriction for using hyphens in the id. its string. This shows you have error somewhere else in your code. Hyphens in the IDs of element cause no issue. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686337/hyphens-or-underscores-in-css-and-html-identifiers This might help you to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
onclick="login_existing_submit();"
```

and also give this onclick event better to an button rather than submit(not sure but its gud)

Answer (score 0):

If this is form you are in trouble. Because in this case onclick handler called but form also get submitted. From your code it seems no trouble.

Also I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2T3XH/1/).